# Have I damaged this DC-DC converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, debugging, damage

I bought this [DC-DC Adjustable Power Converter Module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Adjustable-Power-Converter-Module-LM2577-3-5-35v-Step-up-5-56v-MAX-3A-/261079885939), to convert 12V DC to 5V DC.

Initially it was working fine, but I connected IN- and OUT- pins to the each other and used it as a common ground for LED Display driver which takes both 12V and 5V as input but has one ground. After this it doesn't seem to work, the output voltage is stuck at 1.24V, no matter how much I vary the resistor which is there to control the voltage.

Can you help me find out what component I have damaged and how?

---

Edit 1: This is the schematic of my circuit:

The output of DC-DC converter is 5V, which is fed to the pin 3 of the Display driver, 
I have a major question regarding the connection of ground pins.

[image: Schematic]

The Pinout for the LED Driver is here:
[image]

Datasheet for the driver can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zia2kvfqf0nxd8o/DATA-LED-22042HH_LED%20driver%20for%20M215HW02%20V_0.pdf).

I have questions regarding the ground of the display driver. There are two grounds, are both the same grounds? Should they be connected to the DC-DC converter input ground or output ground?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: There was two downvotes, actually, none of which were mine. But I suppose that you didn't provide schematics to help us understand what was going on with your setup. A picture is worth a thousand words, and at this site, a schematic is worth a million.

Comment: Ok, i am new to this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Anther reason may be that the downvoters considered your question off-topic. Questions purely about fixing a devices are off-topic, but I think yours include some design components, which in my opinion makes it on topic. Having a schematic would help making it more on-topic, though.

Comment: Here's what's on-topic and off-topic: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It does seem to be an evaluation board for Texas/National simple switcher, so it should be perfectly on-topic.

Comment: Sorry for keeping asking for more, but do you have a datasheet or schematic for the converter module itself?

Comment: This (http://tinyurl.com/qz94pk6) is the exact converter that i am using, i was unable to find the datasheet for it. I think it works as the typical application you described in your answer.

Comment: I don't want to fix it, i just want to know the correct way to connect the dc-dc converter and the display driver.

Comment: Well, it's hard to know how to connect the module without a datasheet. For you and for us. I was puzzled by your question because I didn't know the module has two negative connections (IN- and OUT-). I'm not familiar with modules with those connections. I would expect similar modules to just have a single ground connection. So, I think I cannot help you further.

Comment: Also, having this question of yours on hold, I would ask another question on the site asking specifically about how to wire this module of yours. Modify the schematic to illustrate what you tried first when the circuit worked. Then, after you get an answer your satisfied with, post other more specific follow up questions.

Comment: Here - I've [asked the question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101167/why-some-lm25xx-dc-dc-adjustable-step-up-converters-have-two-negative-connection) that may help solve the IN- & OUT- mistery.

Comment: @Ricardo You are a savior. Thanks a ton. Also, I have posted a follow up [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101084/interfacing-12v-5v-dc-dc-converter-and-21-display-driver). I have the schematic there that damaged the board, and i still haven't found a way to correct way to connect the display driver.

Comment: @rajat - Cool! Now *THAT'S* an electronics design question! Let's wait and see if anyone answers it. I'll give it a try later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your module is wired like the Typical Application shown on the [LM2577 datasheet](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm1577.pdf), which I reproduce below:

[image: LM2577 Typical Application schematic]

As per datasheet, \$V_{out}\$ is determined by the following formula:

$$V_{out} = 1.23V (1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2})$$

To get the 1.24V that you're reading, \$R_1\$ must be 0 (zero). Assuming also that \$R_1\$ is the trimpot in your module, I would hazard a guess that either the trimpot is at its lowest value (\$0\Omega\$), or it failed short (burned internally closing the circuit as a wire). In any case, it seems that some component in the module has failed.

Can you measure the resistence between the trimpot contacts with a DMM and check if its really \$0\Omega\$? The measurements were these below, based OP's comment.

> The trimpot seems to be stuck at 5.2 Kohm. Here are the readings:
>
> - \$5.2 k\Omega\$ between pins 1 and 2
> - \$5.2 k\Omega\$ between pins 1 and 3
> - \$0 \Omega\$ between 2-3.
>
> Resistance does not change, even if the rotate the screw on top a lot.

Based on the above evidence, it looks like the trimpot is broken (failed short). If it was working, resistence between 2-3 would increase as you turned the screw, while the resistance between 1-2 would decrease (resistance between 1-3 would remain constant at 5.2Kohm in a working trimpot). Try and replace it and see if the module works again.

Also, based on [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/101168/29792) to this question of mine ([Why some LM25xx DC-DC adjustable step-up converters have two negative connections (IN- & OUT-) instead of only one ground?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101167/why-some-lm25xx-dc-dc-adjustable-step-up-converters-have-two-negative-connection)), both IN- and OUT- connections are likely to be shorted in your module already, so your shorting them could not have damaged the module.

Comment: Ricardo, trimpot seems to be stuck at 5.2 Kohm. Between pin 1-2 5.2khom, between 1-3 5.2ohm , between 2-3 is 0ohm. Resistance dose not change, even if the rotate the screw on top a lot.

Comment: Looks like the trimpot is broken (failed short). If it was working, resistence between 2-3 would increase as you turned the screw, while the resistance between 1-2 would decrease (resistance between 1-3 would remain constant at 5.2Kohm in a working trimpot). Try and replace it and see if the module works again.

Comment: Ok, how could i have damaged it?, does connecting IN- and OUT- will damaged this dc-dc converter.

Comment: We could only verify what you've done if you posted the schematics of your circuit. But it doesn't sound good to short IN and OUT of the module.

Comment: Ricardo please find the schematics and other details in the Edit section

Comment: @rajat - please see the updates I made to my answer.